# Cows in my world?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have been trying all these tips on pocket edition  but you can not cheat with spawn eggs. I don't have any cows and I want to make a cake. Can any one help me? I have searched the whole world but there are no cows.

Comment: Relevant http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/159529/no-cows-in-minecraft-pe-world#159529

Answer (score 1):

In Minecraft P.E., cows don't appear to respawn, and you can't change your game mode to survival mode; this means that it is impossible (correct me if I'm wrong) to obtain more cows. If your world generates without cows, you'll be unable to obtain milk for a cake.

Comment: Do villagers sell milk?

Answer (score 0):

Because the space in the world is limited, "animal spawn control" might help you in this situation.

This means removing or placing blocks on top of all dirt blocks on the surface of the world (removing the grass) except in a fixed area. It will increase their spawn rate and make them all spawn there.